# How to make a login view for django custom user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have made a custom user model using the AbstractUser , removed the username and replaced it with email and extended the model, tried creating superuser and it worked and also created some users by a signup form , logged in the admin interface and it worked however when tried to create a login form for the users it fails

I tried this but it didn't work

```
def LoginView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('accounts:login')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html', {'form':form})
```

then i tried this

```
class LoginView(FormView):
   form_class = AuthenticationForm
   template_name = 'login.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
       email = form.cleaned_data['email']
       password = form.cleaned_data['password']
       user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

    # Check here if the user is an admin
       if user is not None and user.is_active:
           login(self.request, user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
       else:
           return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Obviously i expect the user to be logged in
i think the code in this post is badly formatted. mainly it's my fault as i'm new to this platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've developed almost the same setup that you're describing (I didn't remove the username field, just stopped using it). If you haven't already seen it, Django's documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model is quite helpful.

There are a couple of important things that need to be set up correctly for this to work.

- The `USERNAME_FIELD` on your model should be set to the name of your email field.
- The `AUTH_USER_MODEL` needs to point to your custom user model.

```py
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customauth.MyUser'
```

Since you've removed the username field altogether you might need to subclass `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` and `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` to avoid breaking things, but Django should handle a different authentication field quite well.

If you do wind up needing to subclass the view, https://ccbv.co.uk/LoginView/ is a great place to look over *all* the methods to see what's going on.

**Edit - On Subclassing and it's necessity**

What I was saying about possibly needing to subclass certain things was influenced by https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model. I wasn't sure if there were other parts of the authentication system that would need you to customize them because you removed the username field.

I've read through some of the source code for Django's authentication system. Here's the path that's being followed.

1. When the POST request is made to Django's authentication view the authentication form is validated. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.2/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L191
2. The authenticate function is called. This iterates through the backends set up and tries to authenticate on each of them. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.2/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L62
3. Django's built-in authentication backend gets the user if it exists using the natural key. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.2/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L16
4. We can see in the base manager that the natural key used is the field named by `USERNAME_FIELD`. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.2/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L43
5. If the form is valid, meaning that the user is authenticated properly, the user is then logged in. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.2/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L88

My reaction is that it looks like Django should work out of the box for your use case. You shouldn't need to write a backend. Here's the extent of the code my gut says you should have to write.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url

class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return resolve_url('accounts:login')
```

Comment: can you give more information in subclassing i tried defining a authenticate method in a backends.py file but still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this could be of any use to somebody but I can confirm that Django can authenticate you well with its own Login view if you just replace the username with an email field on your custom user model (as long as you specify the USERNAME_FIELD on the custom user model and are indeed using it by declaring it in the settings).

As I was expecting this behavior I designed a custom HTML form with email/password inputs and used the same principles I would use with the original user model authentication. It was failing though and I understood it was because I wasn't adapting my form to the original Login view expectations or would have worked from the start.

Just make sure to remember that the form HTML input tag for the email address needs to have "type" set to "email" but "id" set to "id_username" and "name" to "username".

This means you can just replace username with an email field and authenticate normally. I did not even declare a Login view for my login form to work, the Django view automacally used from the core is just being called at /accounts/login and working on its own. I'm working on Django 3.2