# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL not redirecting

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm using Django, Mysql and Docker, with a custom user model for Django. After entering correct login details the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='searcher-home'` variable in `settings.py` isn't redirecting to the home page as expected, instead it attempts to redirect to the default path of `/accounts/profile/`. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I've looked elsewhere for answers, but all issues I've found are either looking for `LOGIN_URL` which isn't what I need, or are using custom LoginViews, which I'm not. Any insight would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

For anyone else running into this error, I eventually tried to use a LoginView outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761409/how-to-make-a-login-view-for-django-custom-user), which didn't require the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. Just ensure to have an `AUTH_USER_MODEL` defined in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

retry it like this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/searcher-home/'
```

Comment: I'd tried that unfortunately, and all variations of slashes, commas and quotations for it, it just doesn't seem to work regardless of what I tried.